# How to Change Background Color of Status Bar?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I don't want transculent navigationbar in my app. So, I added this code to change it. It works but there is a little problem. If I use largeTitle navigation, status bar color is looks gray. How can I deal with it ? Thanks in advance.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
   navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
   navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

   UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
```

Comment: So what changed in IOS15 that now the background of the status bar is gray even though my view background and nav bar are .black?

Comment: What if navigation bar is not being used?

Answer (score 3):

You could fix it by adding a subview on top of status-bar using `UIStatusBarManager`.

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .compactMap({$0})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    let statusBar = UIView(frame: (keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame)!)
    statusBar.backgroundColor = .white
    keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
}
```

Comment: Other solution works perfect, thanks for answer anyway :)

Comment: My previous answer was similar to the other solution. Modified it thinking you were trying to change the status bar color instead of navigation bar color.